# material.opacity doesn't work when change position of geometry and material.opacity together

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two cube geometry in my scene.One is farther than anther one. when i only change `material.opacity` of the closer cube it works fine.and can see the farther cube. But when i change `material.opacity` and `position.z` of the closer cube together,I can't see the farther cube.

here is my animation code:

```js
function animate() {
    if(window.animationStart) {
        var material = skyBox.material.materials;
        var l = material.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (material[i].opacity > 0) {
                material[i].opacity -= 0.01;
                material[i].needsUpdate = true;
            }
        }
        skyBox.position.z++;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

I want to make a animation like 『fade-out』 for the close cube, during the animation I want to see the farther cube behind.

I found that if the camera's `position.z` less than the closer cube's `position.z`(camera is in the cube), the farther cube won't be render. is this the reason?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you set `material[i].transparent = true;` in order to "activate" the opacity property?

Comment: yes   when i init the material ,i seted```loader.load(val, function (texture) {
                    resolve(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        transparent:true,
                        map: texture,
                        side: THREE.BackSide
                    }));
                });```